# If I want to examine k-shortest paths of the graph, how much links I will check?

Tags: algorithm, graph, routes, time-complexity, shortest-path

I want to estimate complexity of part of my algorithm. I have set of k-shortest paths, and than algorithm determines critical links according to some criteria. 
I used Yen's algorithm to calculate paths, so they are not disjoint.

In the worst case what is complexity of checking each link of this set? I suppose that each path is at least one hop shorter than the previous...

Comment: wow, that's a very complex question, and I think it's hard to answer this without taking a lot of time, some paper, a pencil and some good books. Also, I'm afraid that your description is too vague to get a definite answer.

Comment: In the worse case you would have (n - 1) + (n - 2) + ... + (n - k) = k*(n - k) edges to look at.

Comment: I thought the same. Thanks Niklas